# "Overclocking" monitor refresh rates

Tags: command-line, games, monitor, overclocking

On windows, using custom resolution utility, i can get up to 90Hz on my laptop screen.
How to attain 90Hz on ubuntu? xrandr doesnt shaw any 90Hz presets because my screen is 60Hz but can run upto 90Hz. please help UwU

Comment: what does `cvt` show for the dimensions you want 90hz?